Conic form of maximizing Sharpe ratio with long-short constraints
I read the blog post of mosek software package and learn how to transform the original form of maximizing the Sharpe ratio to the conic form.
We consider the following optimization problem
$$ \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{r^T x - r_f}{\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}} $$
subject to some portfolio constraint (say for long-only portfolio it needs $\mathbf{1}^T x = 1$ and $x \geq 0$ (meaning that each entry in $x$ is non-negative), where $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector whose entries are $1$. Here, $r \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a given return vector and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a given symmetric semi-positive definite (which represents some covariance matrix).
In the original blog post of mosek, when they start to transform the above optimization problem into the conic form, they additionally assume that $r^T x - r_f > 0$, which is somehow not necessary to impose from the modeling point of view. Also, they only consider the long-only constraint $\mathbf{1}^T x = 1$.
My question is: if we remove the positive constraint for the adjusted return $r^T x - r_f >0$ and consider the long-short constraint, that is, we consider the same optimization problem
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{r^T x - r_f}{\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}}$$
but subject to the following constraints
$$ \mathbf{1}^T x^+ = 1, \quad \mathbf{1}^T x^- =-1, \quad \text{and} \quad -1 \leq x \leq 1,$$
where $x^+ = \max\{x,0\}$ and $x^- = \min \{x,0\}$ (element-wise $\max$ and $\min$), then what is the equivalent conic form (if any) and how do we derive such formulation?
